# How can I retrieve and compare two values from a file?

Tags: text-processing, csv

How can I retrieve and compare two values from the first two lines of a file?
I have the following text:

```
05-24-2016, 2:59:32,0,0
05-24-2016, 2:59:37,0,0
05-24-2016, 2:59:42,0,0
05-24-2016, 2:59:47,0,0
05-24-2016, 2:59:52,0,0
05-24-2016, 2:59:57,0,0
05-24-2016, 3:00:02,0,0
```

and I need to compare the first row's values in a particular column (e.g. 2:59:52)
and check the difference in seconds.

I am using the following command but still I am not getting it

```
awk '{ print $2 }' <filename>
```

Only the difference between the first two rows is required (and the rest of the rows should be ignored).

Comment: could you please elaborate your question bit more, its pretty unclear. what is your expected output ?

Comment: I need to check the time difference in the file so I need to retrieve the first two time values (ie. 2:59:32) from the file and compare

Comment: This is how you will split seconds in each line:  awk -F "," '{split($2,a,/:/);print a[3]}' <filename>

Comment: The file is in this format :
05-24-2016, 2:46:11,0,0
05-24-2016, 2:46:16,0,0
05-24-2016, 2:46:21,0,0
So I need only 2:46:11 & 2:46:16 and compare the time difference in seconds

Comment: @don_crissti - As stated in the comment, this is to split seconds only in each line.

Comment: Currently ALL of the examples show only one time value. How can one have a time _difference_ with only one value to compare?

Comment: @don_crissti I see only one date/timestamp per line. The questions says, "I need to retrieve the first two time values" but then goes on to show only one value in its example. I'm trying to understand what is actually required.

Comment: Hi Don, my awk version is GNU Awk 3.1.7
and the expected value is 5 which is the difference in seconds (2:46:11 & 2:46:16), but not necessary that it has to be these values , since the file keeps getting updated , I want to compare the columns in the first two rows

Comment: will the first two lines' timestamps always be within the same day? would you get "05-24-2016 23:59:59" followed by "05-25-2016 00:00:15" ? Will the first line always be smaller/earlier than the second?

Comment: @Taher, if the answers allowed you to solve your problem, please "accept" the one you found most useful by clicking on the big check mark to its left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shell script will get you the difference in seconds between the timestamps in column two of the first two rows:

```
( IFS=, read -r _ a _; IFS=, read -r _ b _; a=$(date --date $a +%s); b=$(date --date $b +%s); echo "$a - $b" | bc | tr -d - ) <filename
```

It can be broken down like this, too, if you prefer:

```
(
    IFS=, read -r junk a junk        # Get second comma separated field
    IFS=, read -r junk b junk
    a=$(date --date $a +%s)          # Convert to seconds since the epoch
    b=$(date --date $b +%s)
    echo "$a - $b" | bc | tr -d -    # Compute signed difference, then discard unary minus sign
) <filename
```

Comment: Nice use of `date`! But *of course* it should be broken down. It's not a one-liner just because the newlines were left out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get out the first two timestamps:

```
head -2 mydata.csv | awk -F, '{print$2}'
```

"Comparing" the times is a harder problem. If you just want to know which one is earlier, you can ask `sort` to check if they are in sorted order:

```
if head -2 mydata.csv | awk -F, '{print$2}' | sort -c 2> /dev/null
then
    echo "The first timestamp is earlier than the second"
else
    echo "The first timestamp is later than the second"
fi
```

If you actually need to compute and display the difference between the timestamps, that's a different question. You could adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8168656/699305) (for awk), or just google for your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` script will get you the difference in seconds between the timestamps in column two of the first two rows

```
awk -F, '{ cmd = "date --date " $2 " +%s "; cmd | getline sec[NR] } NR>2 { exit } END { print (sec[2] > sec[1]) ? (sec[2] - sec[1]) : (sec[1] - sec[2]) }' <filename
```

It can be broken down like this, too, if you prefer:

```
awk -F, '
    # Read a line, get column two and convert it to seconds since the epoch
    { cmd = "date --date " $2 " +%s "; cmd | getline sec[NR] }

    # After two lines start to exit
    NR>2 { exit }

    # At exit print the absolute value of the difference between the two times
    END { print (sec[2] > sec[1]) ? (sec[2] - sec[1]) : (sec[1] - sec[2]) }

' <filename
```